# List Children of Current Post Type Page ONLY

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

Odd request but I have a custom post type "Proofs" which has different child pages in it.

Parent 1
Parent 2
   -Child1
   -Child 2
Parent 3
   -Child4

When I'm on a parent page I want it to list the children of itself. Not all the children in the custom post type, but only the children below it.

So when I'm on Parent2 I only see Child1 and Child2 listed. Seems pretty straightforward but I can't crack it.

Answer (score 0):

Using [**WP_Query**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query):

```
<?php
$id = get_the_ID();
$q = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type'=>'proofs',
    //'post__in'=>array($id), //Uncomment this if you want to include the parent
    'post_parent'=>$id
));
?>
<ul>
<?php while($q->have_posts()) : $q->the_post(); ?>
    <li><?php the_title(); ?></li>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</ul>
```

Using [**wp_list_pages**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages):

```
<?php
$id = get_the_ID();
wp_list_pages(array(
    'child_of'=>$id,
    'post_type'=>'proofs'
));
?>
```

wp_list_pages is a much simpler approach, but you have less control over how it renders its markup without employing your own Walker. My advice would be to use WP_Query if you need to easily tailor the output to your needs. Otherwise, if you're just looking for a list of links, wp_list_pages is fine.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. I wish I could get you more info, but I tried that and nothing shows up. The post type name is correct

Comment: Glad we got it on the first shot. When you can, please mark this as answered in case anybody else might have a similar question.